# Firebase Nodejs - after get listCollections

Tags: node.js, firebase

I want to get a collection of subCollections,

```
admin.firestore()
    .collection(SCHEDULE_COLLECTION)
    .doc(user)
    .listCollections()
    .then(collections  => {
        const cId = [];
        collections.forEach(collection => {

        });
        return res.send(cId);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    });
```

I'm getting here ID, 
Now I want to get the collections under
[this object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pilUn.png)

How I can do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are not subcollections.  What you circled are fields in a single document.  Just read build a reference to the document and read it like you normally would with `get()`.  "events" and "foods" will be array type fields in the document snapshot.

```
const ref = admin.firestore()
    .collection(SCHEDULE_COLLECTION)
    .doc(user)
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(...)
    .get()
```

You'll have to query the collection to get the list of documents if you don't know the document ID.